# Thread Kill Issue in Eclipse Jetty WebSocket client after error

Tags: websocket, client, jetty

```
QueuedThreadPool: WebSocketClient@122503328{STOPPING,8<=8<=200,i=5,q=7} Couldn't stop Thread[WebSocketClient@122503328-1556,5,main]
QueuedThreadPool: WebSocketClient@122503328{STOPPING,8<=8<=200,i=4,q=7} Couldn't stop Thread[WebSocketClient@122503328-1557,5,main]
QueuedThreadPool: WebSocketClient@122503328{STOPPING,8<=8<=200,i=4,q=7} Couldn't stop Thread[WebSocketClient@122503328-1560,5,main]
QueuedThreadPool: WebSocketClient@122503328{STOPPING,8<=8<=200,i=4,q=7} Couldn't stop Thread[WebSocketClient@122503328-1561,5,main]
QueuedThreadPool: WebSocketClient@122503328{STOPPING,8<=8<=200,i=4,q=7} Couldn't stop Thread[WebSocketClient@122503328-1563,5,main]
```

The above warning log is seen repeatedly and system performance is impacted when we try to stop the client using WebSocketClient stop() method. The stop timeout is set to 0.

This is occurring when server application on 3rd party machine is down and connection is refused since no server is listening on destination port. Connect Exception is seen in onError callback.

This warning is seen even if disconnect and close are done from a different thread than the client thread.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using a Thread from the ThreadPool to attempt to stop that same thread pool.

Don't call `.stop()` from a Jetty thread.

Schedule the stop on a new thread of your own making.